# Scroll to top of previous terminal command

Tags: terminal, external-command, scrolling

I am using vim to compile my code using the command `:w | !make`.

If this output produces a lot of compiler errors (not uncommon lol), then I'd like to scroll to the top of the output, where the command was executed, so that I can handle the first error first.

My terminal has a 'scroll to last command' feature, but of course the last actual command that the terminal is aware of is `>vim ...`, so this feature doesn't take me to the top of the last command executed from *vim* - it takes me to the the top of all the output from vim since i started the session.

Is there a way to scroll my terminal to the last external command? I'm imagining something like `w | !make | <scroll-to-last-command>`.

Comment: Do not make "!make". Make yourself to see `:h :make` instead.

Comment: Since you're using `!`, the scroll in question pertains to an external terminal and not to Vim, making this off-topic. Inside Vim using `:terminal`, you could backwards-search for the prompt (interactive programs, like the shell) or use `gg` (batch programs). I'm inclined to let this stand, though, since Matt hints at an answer around using built-in facilities which might "redeem" the question.